# What is the problem in rebuild of ns2 after adding multiple file as macng.cc and macng.h?

Tags: macos, ns2, rebuild

[I added multiple files as macng.cc and macng.h but when rebuild , ns2 do not run and do not install, and there is error with ns command .and do not created macng.o file.
make depend , make clean , make ; are rebuild commands.
after rebuild ns command say ns has problem
where is the problem ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZLBC.jpg)

Comment: 1. Please show errors (the last 5 lines) as text, not as an image https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text , i.e. **Edit** your question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70567803/edit .... 2. Do not add / edit files, use the patch, or install the APP https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1o60CwKUU9hzt2Nvb1iX2jQQFKFSuBYX_?usp=sharing

Comment: `[code ommited because of length] Mac/Macng set fullduplex_mode_ 0` : Please tell what you are supposed to build, is it CRCN? Or? ........ The errors indicate a failed build : Only old 32bits OS can build crcn. Ubuntu 10.10 - i386 or CentOS 6.10 - i386 https://vault.centos.org/6.10/isos/i386/CentOS-6.10-i386-LiveDVD.iso

Comment: yes it is CRCN and fedoracore4 32bit

Comment: CRCN installed on ns2-2.31 and fedoracore4 already by others.

Comment: ns-2.31 + CRCN + Fedora 4 : Of course, in year 2005 ... and later it was Fedora 12, or the Fedora 12 based CentOS 6 → supported till 2020 . .... And for the current supported, e.g. Fedora 34 - 64bit, the app `crcn-ns231-1.el5.i386.rpm` is perfect.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Build ns-2.31 + CRCN with Fedora 4? .. Fedora 7 : Unpack a new ns-allinone-2.31.tar.gz into a new folder. **1**. You can have as many ns-2.xx as you want, installed at the same time. **2**. A wrecked ns2 may not be usable for a rebuild.

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.31.tar.gz
cd ns-allinone-2.31
patch -p0 < crcn_ns231.patch
./install
cd ns-2.31/
cp ns ns-crcn
# cp ns-crcn /usr/local/bin/
----- Simulation ------
ns-crcn test4macng.tcl
```

The ~15 CRCN ex : crcn-examples-3.tar.gz
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rKj5gBrgpG1z_xDBWONP5mGNq7lUhlbT/view?usp=sharing

The ~300 ns2 patches https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNZ2lWZDBRSW40Q00?resourcekey=0-eBw6mJFKhSVGultqaD2rDA&usp=sharing

ns2 INFO https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dbrFE8CDMNbE5Kmq4duZl6bUTP7PXdVps9AGvzVi0gM/edit?usp=sharing